# open form in infopath filler from document library

Tags: infopath

I created an "InfoPath filler form template" in InfoPath 2010 and submitted it to a SharePoint Server Standard 2010 document library. When I click on the document link in the document library, I get the following error message:

> The form template was created with a newer version of InfoPath.
>   This form template was created by InfoPath version 14.0.0.

Based on the information [on this blog](http://blog.sharepointelearning.com/licensing-requirements-for-infopath-forms-on-sharepoint/), I do not think it is a licensing problem.

Why does this occur? As mentioned above, I am using the 2010 edition of both InfoPath and SharePoint.

Edited to add: I want the form to open in InfoPath form filler, not in the browser.

Comment: Do you have Infopath 2007 and 2010 installed on your machine? I would reccomend uninstalling Office 2010 and reinstalling it - for some reason, your PC is under the impression that the default Infopath application is before version 14.0.0 (2010)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have Office 2007 installed (my organization has not upgraded yet), but InfoPath 2010. Ooh, now I have a reason to install Office 2010! :)

Comment: No problems - let me know if it works, and i'll repost it as an answer!

Comment: @Mike - I uninstalled just InfoPath 2007, kept the rest of Office 2007, and kept InfoPath 2010. Everything works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Office 2007 after having Infopath (or all of office) 2010 installed will replace the file extension association of office files (Including Infopath) with the 2007 applications.

To resolve this issue, you can either reinstall Office 2010 to reinforce the file associations, or uninstall the 2007 version of the software.